# Magento REST API - "Invalid Content-Type header" on POST method

Tags: json, rest, http, magento

I am trying to run a POST call to create a new customer on Magento from another platform using "http://magentohost/api/rest/customers".

The request failed with this message:

```
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":400,"message":"Invalid Content-Type header"}]}}
```

Yet I specify well the `Content-Type` as follows:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization : ...
```

body is something like this:

```
{"website_id":"1","email":"test@test.com","telephone":"","group_id":"1","prefix":"Mme","firstname":"test","lastname":"test"}
```

the request works fine when I fire it from chrome rest client with the same settings.

also GET method works fine.

If some one encountred the same issue please help !

Comment: Not a solution, but a POST call has no accept header. It only has a content-type header.

Comment: Which client are you using? Are you using some code to execute Magento REST API? If yes, how are you setting Content-Type header?

Comment: @JordyV the Accept header field can be used on any request that expects a non-empty response.

Comment: thanks for the reply guys, 
client is a jssp (http://jssp.sourceforge.net/)
my call is like this :

var http = new HttpClientRequest();
http.header["Accept"] = "application/json";
http.header["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
http.url = "http://mySite/api/rest/customers"
http.method = "POST";
http.body = json ...
http.execute();
"HttpClientRequest" is an object that lets you perform certain operations as an HTTP client.(the name is explicit).

Comment: according to the doc The following headers are required for the call:

    /Authorization
    /Version
    /Accept
    /Content-type, i dont know what "Version" stand for (http version ?)

Comment: @Idham do you have solution for this??

Comment: @Eric yesterday, for some reason my server was duplicating the Charset  value, So the problem wasn't with the API.

Comment: I have same problem. Anyone have solution?